# I want to update one attribute of an element in carts without updating database. What should I write in edit method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class CartController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
        }

        // GET: Cart
        private NorthwindDataContext dbContext = new NorthwindDataContext();
        private List<Cart> carts;
        public List<Cart> GetListCarts()
        {
            carts = Session["Cart"] as List<Cart>;
            if (carts == null)
            { 
                carts = new List<Cart>();
                Session["Cart"] = carts;
            }
            return carts;
        }
        public ActionResult AddCart(int id)
        {
            carts = GetListCarts();
            Cart c = carts.Find(s => s.ProductID == id);
            if (c == null)
            {
                c = new Cart(id);
                carts.Add(c);
            }
            else
                c.Quantity++;
            return RedirectToAction("ListCarts");
        }
        public ActionResult ListCarts()
        {
            carts = GetListCarts();
            ViewBag.CountProduct = carts.Sum(s=>s.Quantity);
            ViewBag.Total = carts.Sum(s => s.Total);
            return View(carts);
        }
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            carts = GetListCarts();
            var p = carts.Find(s => s.ProductID == id);
            return View(p);
        }
        [HttpPatch]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            carts = GetListCarts();
            int c = carts.FindIndex(s => s.ProductID == id);
            if (c != -1)
                carts[c].Quantity = int.Parse(collection["Quantity"]);   
            UpdateModel(carts);
            return RedirectToAction("ListCarts");
        }
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            carts = GetListCarts();
            Cart c = carts.Find(s => s.ProductID == id);

            if (c != null) 
                carts.RemoveAll(s=>s.ProductID== id);
            return RedirectToAction("ListCarts");
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Cart
    {
        private NorthwindDataContext dbContext = new NorthwindDataContext();

        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal? Total { get => UnitPrice * Quantity; }

        public Cart(int pID)
        {
            this.ProductID = pID;
            Product p = dbContext.Products.Single(n=>n.ProductID==pID);
            ProductName = p.ProductName;
            UnitPrice = p.UnitPrice;
            Quantity = 1;
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Cart

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Cart</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductID, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductName, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UnitPrice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UnitPrice, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Tried:
When I clicked Edit then Save button, nothing happened.

```
[HttpPatch]     
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            carts = GetListCarts();
            int c = carts.FindIndex(s => s.ProductID == id);
            if (c != -1)
                carts[c].Quantity = int.Parse(collection["Quantity"]);   
            UpdateModel(carts);
            return RedirectToAction("ListCarts");
        }
```

Expected:
When I click Edit, the page moves to Edit View and I can change Quantity field then I click Save button. After that, the page redirects to ListCarts and the field I changed should be updated. But there is something wrong in the above code, please fix me. Fmi, I changed some fields to readonly textbox in Edit View. Does that affect the method?

Comment: you are not updating your session variable `Carts` in the `Edit` method.

Comment: @RajeshG how to do that?

Comment: add `Session["Cart"] = carts;` before return statement in your `Edit` method.

Comment: @RajeshG already did that but it didn't work